# Lemma about composite fields in Weintraub's "Galois Theory"

Tags: field-theory, proof-explanation, galois-theory

I'm working through Weintraub's Galois theory book and I'm having trouble understanding the following lemma (which as I understand will be used later on). So, given a base field $F$, its extension $E$, and subfields $B,D$ that are themselves extensions of $F$, i.e. $F\subset B,D\subset E$, Weintraub defines the composite field $BD$ as the smallest field containing both subfields and makes a passing comment about how it consists of all expressions of the form $\big(\sum_i b_id_i\big)\big(\sum_j b_jd_j\big)^{-1}$ (I suppose this is plausible). He goes on to state and prove the following lemma, about the case where the denominators $\big(\sum_j b_jd_j\big)^{-1}$ may be omitted:

> [With $F,E,B,D$ defined as above] suppose $|D:F|$ is finite. Then $|BD:B|\leq|D:F|$ and $BD=\{\sum_i b_id_i\}$.

> Proof: Let $K=\{\sum_i b_id_i\}$ and $\{\delta_j\}$ be a basis of $D$ over $F$, then $\{\delta_i\}$ spans $K$ over $B$ (I suppose this is true, just express the $d_i$s in $\sum_i b_id_i$ terms of the basis and you get a $B$-linear combination of the basis vectors), therefore $|K:B|\leq|D:F|$ and [by a previous lemma, about how a finite-dimensional integral domain is a field] $K$ is field. Therefore $BD=K$.

I do not understand the last step, why from the fact that $K$ is a field does it follow that it is equal to the composite $BD$? Aside from a technical explanation of why this works, some intuition as to why we can dispense with denominators in this case would be helpful as well. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $K$ equals $BD$ follows because both $B$ and $D$ are definitely contained in $K$ (note that $K$ was defined as the set of all sums of products of elements of $B$ with elements of $D$; it contains $B$ by taking a sum with a single summand and expressing $b\in B$ as $b\cdot 1$, and symmetrically for $D$). Since $BD$ is, by definition, the smallest field that contains both $B$ and $D$, if $K$ is indeed a field then this shows that $BD\subseteq K$. But since you already noted that $BD$ is the set of all products of elements of the set $K$ *and inverses of elements of the set $K$*, then we have $K\subseteq BD$, giving the desired equality.

The intuition is essentially that in a finite field extension, the inverse of an element $\alpha$ can be written as a polynomial in $\alpha$: for if $F\leq E$ is an extension, and $\alpha\in E$, then $|F(\alpha):F|$ is finite, so there is an $n\gt 0$ such that $1$, $\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^n$ is linearly independent. Picking the smallest such $n$ we get an expression of the form
$$a_0 + a_1\alpha + \cdots +a_n\alpha^n=0$$
with $a_0\neq 0$, and from this we get $\alpha(a_1+a_2\alpha+\cdots+a_n\alpha^{n-1}) = -a_0$, so
$$\frac{1}{\alpha} = -\frac{1}{a_0}\left(a_1+a_2\alpha_\cdots+a_n\alpha^{n-1}\right).$$
Similarly, any element $\alpha=\sum_i b_id_i$ has an inverse, which can be expressed as a polynomial expression in $\alpha$, so you don't have to explicitly throw in the multiplicative inverse of $\alpha$, it comes for free once you throw  in $\alpha$ and close under ring operations.

Thus, the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ which includes $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, does not require you to also throw in $1/(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ explicitly, since it can be expressed as
$$10\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\right) - \left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\right)^3$$
(you can verify this by multiplying this expression by $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ and seeing that you get $1$).